# Problema con llamada de funcion

Tags: c++

Estoy con un proyecto en el que trabajo con varias clases una de estas es la clase liga la cual almacena diferentes jornadas con memoria dinámica. Por otro lado tengo una case Jornada, es esta tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
int CJornada::PuntsTotalsJornada(CJornada& jornada)
{
    int tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<m_numPartits;i++)
    {
        tmp = jornada.m_partits[i].PuntsTotal();
        m_puntsTotalsJornada=m_puntsTotalsJornada+tmp;
    }
    return m_puntsTotalsJornada;
}
```

Intento llamarla desde la clase Liga con la siguiente función, pero no consigo que funcione:

```
void
CLliga::MostraJornadaAmbMesPunts(ostream& os)
{
    //os<<"La Jornada amb mes punts es la i amb Puntostotales"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m_numJornades;i++)
    {
        CJornada::PuntsTotalsJornada(m_Jornades[i]);
    }
}
```

Me enseña el siguiente error, pero no se me ocurre como arreglarlo: cannot call member function `int CJornada::PuntsTotalsJornada(CJornada&)` without object

Este sería el constructor de Liga:

```
CLliga::CLliga()
{
    // Estableix el valor per defecte de les variables de CLliga
    m_nomLliga = ("????");
    m_temporada = ("0000-0000");
    m_Jornades = 0;
    m_numJornades = 0;
}
```

Y sus atributos:

```
private:
    CCadena  m_nomLliga;
    CCadena m_temporada;
    CJornada *m_Jornades;
    int m_numJornades;
```

Añado que el atributo `M_Jornades` es una lista de jornadas que contiene atributos como el numero de partidos, adjunto su constructor y atributos para aclarar:

```
CJornada::CJornada()
{
    // Defineix aqui el constructor per defecte
    m_partits = 0;
    m_numPartits = 0;
    m_idJornada = 0;
    m_puntsTotalsJornada=0;
}

private:

    CPartit *m_partits;
    int m_numPartits;
    int m_idJornada;
    int m_puntsTotalsJornada;
```

Comment: Podrias por favor mostrar los atributos de la clase liga así como su constructor?

Comment: ¿No se debería cambiar el nombre de la pregunta por la expresión del error mas descriptivamente?, así se podría encontrar mejor al momento de buscarla. me parece una pregunta muy interesante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLiga` tiene como miembro `m_Jornades`, que es un puntero de tipo `CJornada`. Como bien indicas, `m_Jornades` contiene una lista con todas las jornadas disponibles.

Lo que tienes que hacer es proporcionar una referencia concreta a una de esas jornadas para que la función sepa a con qué elemento tiene que interactuar. Una posibilidad sería pasarle el índice:

```
void CLliga::MostraJornadaAmbMesPunts(ostream& os, size_t indiceJornada)
{
  for(int i=0;i<m_numJornades;i++)
  {
    m_Jornades[indiceJornada].PuntsTotalsJornada(m_Jornades[i]);
  }
}
```

O el identificador de la jornada. En este caso te toca iterar en `m_Jornades` para localizar el elemento que posee el identificador:

```
// Ignoro si ya dispones de una función similar a esta
CJornada* CLliga::BuscarJornada(int idJornada)
{
  CJornada* jornada = nullptr; // o 0 si no compilas con C++11

  for( int i=0; i<m_numJornades && nullptr == jornada; i++ )
  {
    if( m_Jornades[i].IdJornada() == idJornada )
      jornada = &m_Jornades[i];
  }

  return jornada;
}

void CLliga::MostraJornadaAmbMesPunts(ostream& os, int idJornada)
{
  CJornada* jornada = BuscarJornada(idJornada);

  if( nullptr != jornada )
  {
    for(int i=0;i<m_numJornades;i++)
    {
      jornada->PuntsTotalsJornada(m_Jornades[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que lo que quieres es **llamar** a un método sin necesidad de aplicarlo sobre una instancia.

Para ello, no tienes mas que declarar el método como `static`. Cambiando tu clase `CJornada`:

```
class CJornada {
public:
  static int PuntsTotalsJornada( CJornada& jornada );
// ^^^ Añadido
  ...
};
```

Aplicada a funciones dentro de clases, permite precisamente eso: llamarlas **sin necesidad de instancia**.

Ten en cuenta que, dentro de métodos `static`, **no puedes acceder a `this`**, puesto que `this` es, precisamente, un *puntero* a la instancia; ya dijimos que los métodos `static` **no tienen**.

`static` se aplica **en la declaración**; el cuerpo de la función queda tal cual, **no** le puede aplicar.

Ten en cuenta que las funciones `static`, al no tener `this`, **tampoco** pueden acceder a los demás atributos de clase **que no sean, a su vez, estáticos**.

Comment: Creo que no lo soluciona pues tengo atributos que no son estáticos y me muestra los siguientes errores:  invalid use of member 'CJornada::m_numPartits' in static member function                                                
invalid use of member 'CJornada::m_puntsTotalsJornada' in static member function

Comment: @ElPatrón Entonces, no tengo ni idea de lo que quieres hacer.  En esa función haces `tmp = jornada.m_partits[i].PuntsTotal();`; es decir, sabes como llamar a métodos de instancia en un *arreglo*. No hay mas. O llamas a funciones de instancia, o llamas a funciones estáticas.

Answer (score 0):

A menos que la función sea delara estática:

```
static int CJornada::PuntsTotalsJornada(CJornada& jornada) {
    int tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<m_numPartits;i++) {
        tmp = jornada.m_partits[i].PuntsTotal();
        m_puntsTotalsJornada=m_puntsTotalsJornada+tmp;
    }
    return m_puntsTotalsJornada;
}
```

debería instanciar el objeto para poder llamar a esa función:

```
void CLliga::MostraJornadaAmbMesPunts(ostream& os) {

    CJornada cJornada;

    //os<<"La Jornada amb mes punts es la i amb Puntostotales"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m_numJornades;i++)
    {
        cJornada.PuntsTotalsJornada(m_Jornades[i]);
    }
}
```